# compute $\frac{10-c}{2017(a+b)}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

if $a+b+c=10$ then what is the value of $$\frac{10-c}{2017(a+b)}$$

I dont really know how to solved this , but I noticed when $c=10$ and $a+b=0$ indeed its satisfied $a+b+c=10$ , but it will gave me some undefined problem , any idea ?

Comment: hint: $a+b+c = 10\implies a + b = 10-c$

Comment: aaaah okey , ill try

Comment: 1/2017 as the soluton

Comment: good job. the answer is right.

Comment: If this is contest math without a proof required, personally I would just plug in $1,0,9$ for $a,b,c$ and evaluate to ensure speed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try to express $a+b$ in terms of $10$ and $c$ then try to simplify terms.

Remark: if your concern is what if $a+b=0$, well, we have to avoid that. It is possible for that quantity to be undefined when $a+b=0$. Other than that, it is equal to a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

If $a + b + c =10$ then $10 -c = a+ b$.

What is $\frac {a+b}{2017(a+b)}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $c=10$ then the needed value does not exist.

If $c\neq10$ then
$$\frac{10-c}{2017(a+b)}=\frac{10-c}{2017(10-c)}=\frac{1}{2017}.$$